# docs on SPAN tag on rails, or is this something specific to activeadmin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, activeadmin

Those of you familar with activeadmin, you can do something like this in your admin controllers

```
span "Some Title" :class =>'edit_parent_category_link' do
    (code here)
end
```

If you try putting html in place for "Some Title", it just prints it with the tags and dont render the html.

Where can I get more info on this span so I can modify it? Is this something built into rails or is this just for activeadmin?

Pardon me if this is a noob question; started rails 2 days ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an excellent question. It's active admin, not Rails built it.

Active Admin documentation: http://activeadmin.info/documentation.html

You can modify it as you create it by using attributes like this:

```
span "Some Title" :class =>'foo', :height => '20', :width => '50' do
    (code here)
end
```

If there's other ways you want to modify it, add a comment and I'll do my best to help.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Is there no way to drop html in place of the "Some Title"? It encodes the html and prints the actual html instead of rendering it. I'm trying to add a "Edit | Delete" links in there so the span data looks nice and clean.